# How do i return number of empty array's based on the limit in PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Am looking for a solution 
here are the details
Assume : req.params.collage_id = 1;
    As i have only 2 records found for collage 1, so only 2 records are displaying. instead of this , the empty braces has to be displayed if there is no data, please help me out here.

```
db.query('SELECT * from students where collage_id = $1 limit 4',[req.params.collage_id],function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    res.send(result.rows);
    })

output:

    [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "XYZ",
                "DOB" :3-12-1999
            },
             {
                "_id": 4,
                "name": "XYZ",
                "DOB" :3-1-1999
            }
        ]

    Expected output
    [
    {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "XYZ",
                "DOB" :3-12-1999
            },
             {
                "_id": 4,
                "name": "XYZ",
                "DOB" :3-1-1999
            },
    {},
    {}
    ]
```

Comment: Thats is not what `where` clause does. It select only the matched result. You can remove the `where` clause and use `*` then loop over the result & create a new array. This new array will have matched elements and rest empty objects

Comment: you can manipulate the results .

Comment: @brk should i give the `result` length while loop over the result? `var total = media_res.rows.length total -= 1
                if(total <= 0){res.send(array)}` if so i did it but i am not getting that empty objects , it just displayed the available records